# PHP: passthru and register_shutdown_function

Tags: php, passthru

I am having strange issue. I have a script that causes download using passthru() - I want to record into database when user is downloading file...

To do this, I have register_shutdown_function() before passthru but it gets called without file being downloaded completely.

```
<?php
// add to database that user is downloading file

// rest of code here 
...
register_shutdown_function('download_ended');
passthru ("curl -r $start-$end --limit-rate 400K '$file'");
exit; 

function download_ended(){
    // remove from database download info
}
?>
```

The function download_ended() gets called even if file is still downloading. How can I remove entry from database once file has downloaded completely or interrupted by user?

Comment: Register shutdown function is called as a part of the request, so when the request terminates it gets called (as opposed to response).  Any reason why you aren't just using your weblogs to trace this?

Comment: @Saeven Thanks for pointing out.. Any idea how I can accomplish this any other way?

Comment: Can you try removing the "exit;" statement and see what you get

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash tried that already. No difference

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code and apply the following to accomplish a callback on file transfer completion process, making a useful usage of [PHP's Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php) (If you're using PHP >= 5.3.0):

```
<?php
 $file = function($url, $path) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return file_put_contents($path, $data);
 };

 if (FALSE !== $file('http://www.example.com/img.jpg', '/tmp/img.jpg')) {
   download_ended();
 }
```

Note that i have used PHP's curl commands instead of native call.

Hope this helps in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question, you want to limit the upload rate, and do some database tagging when done. You'll need to step outside of CURL and rely on PHP's native functions to get something like this done.

```
<?php

    set_time_limit( 0 );

    // do database stuff here

    $of     = fopen($file, "rb");    
    $dlrate = 400;

    while(!feof($of)) 
    {
        print fread($of, round($dlrate * 1024));    
        flush();
        sleep(1);    
    }    

    fclose($of);

    // do more database stuff here
```

You can use a timestamp to tally dropped downloads.

Comment: I can't use fread() because the file is remotely hosted and inorder to support byte ranges I have to use CURL.